# How to install Laravel app in subfolder

Tags: php, apache, laravel, .htaccess, subdirectory

I have a PHP site on www.domain.com, and I want to run a laravel project on www.domain.com/my-project, but I don't know what I need to change to do this.

I'm trying to edit apache conf, but always laravel project override the project on domain.

**laravel.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 127.0.0.1
    Alias /my-project /var/www/html/my-project/public
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/my-project/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/my-project>
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I also tried to edit .htaccess to rewrite base, but I have the same problem. Laravel project runs on www.domain.com/my-project, but www.domain.com also runs laravel project.

**.htaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /my-project/

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

So, I don't know if its possible and how to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: VirtualHosts are for qualified domain names, not subfolders.